# How to use type variable in Haskell instance-where

Tags: haskell, types, instance

I try to use type variable in the where-body of the type instance. But GHC
 don't use the type variable for the functions in the type instance.

I try to implement type class `Bits` for `[a]`.

```
instance forall a. Bits a => Bits [a] where
    xor = zipWith xor
    rotateL list dis = keeped .|. overlap
    where
        overlap = tail moved ++ [head moved] 
        (keeped, moved) = unzip $ map (\n -> let rot = rotate n dis in (rot.&.mask, rot.&.filter)) list
        mask = (complement 0) `shiftL` dis -- this line
        filter = complement mask
```

GHC says:

```
Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal ‘0’
```

Expected:

That `0` is expected to be as type `a`, which is the type variable as defined in `instance forall a. Bits a => Bits [a]`

Comment: The problem here isn't that ghc doesn't use the type variable a. It does! You can tell it has inferred that 0 should have the type `a`, because it is complaining that `a` (arising from the literal 0) is not known to be an instance of `Num`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to write "zero" in different contexts.

You only have a constraint `Bits a`, then one way to write "zero" is `zeroBits`.

`0` is the "zero" for types that have a `Num a` instance.

Comment: For future visitors with similar error messages: another solution is to leave the method definitions the same, but add the required constraint to the instance context, as in `instance (Num a, Bits a) => Bits [a] where ...`. It's not the right solution in this case, but in other similar cases it frequently is.